# create file on server and download js

Tags: javascript, excel, axios

I have a function that opens an Excel file saved on the server and edits some variables entered by the user, what I want with this file is that after editing it with the variables entered by the user it is saved or downloaded to the user's computer locally from the server

this is the back:

```
function hojaDeVida(BD, carpeta, sheetName, tipoDeDocumento, documento, nombreCompleto, direccion, telefono, celular, correoEmpleado, genero, fechaDeNacimiento, estadoCivil, numeroDeHijos,
        fechaDeIngreso, fechaDeRetiro, cargo, observacion, centroDeCostos, turno, tipoDeContrato, salario, nombreDeBanco, tipoDeCuenta, numeroDeCuenta,
        tallaDelantal, tallaSudadera, tallaJeans, tallaZapatos, cajaDeCompensacion, fondoDeCesantias, fondoDePensiones, eps, arl, nivelDeRiesgo) {
        const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        wb.xlsx.readFile(BD)
            .then(() => {
                const ws = wb.getWorksheet(sheetName);
                ws.getCell("C3").value = tipoDeDocumento;
                ws.getCell("C4").value = documento;
                ws.getCell("C5").value = nombreCompleto;
                ws.getCell("C6").value = direccion;
                ws.getCell("C7").value = telefono;
                ws.getCell("C8").value = celular;
                ws.getCell("C9").value = correoEmpleado;
                ws.getCell("C10").value = genero;
                ws.getCell("C11").value = fechaDeNacimiento;
                ws.getCell("C12").value = estadoCivil;
                ws.getCell("C13").value = numeroDeHijos;
                ws.getCell("C15").value = fechaDeIngreso;
                ws.getCell("C16").value = fechaDeRetiro;
                ws.getCell("C17").value = cargo;
                ws.getCell("C18").value = observacion;
                ws.getCell("C19").value = centroDeCostos;
                ws.getCell("C20").value = turno;
                ws.getCell("C21").value = tipoDeContrato;
                ws.getCell("C22").value = salario;
                ws.getCell("C24").value = nombreDeBanco;
                ws.getCell("C25").value = tipoDeCuenta;
                ws.getCell("C26").value = numeroDeCuenta;
                ws.getCell("C28").value = tallaDelantal;
                ws.getCell("C29").value = tallaSudadera;
                ws.getCell("C30").value = tallaJeans;
                ws.getCell("C31").value = tallaZapatos;
                ws.getCell("C33").value = cajaDeCompensacion;
                ws.getCell("C34").value = fondoDeCesantias;
                ws.getCell("C35").value = fondoDePensiones;
                ws.getCell("C36").value = eps;
                ws.getCell("C37").value = arl;
                ws.getCell("C38").value = nivelDeRiesgo;
                wb.xlsx.writeFile(`${carpeta}/13) Hoja de vida.xlsx`);
            });
    };
```

And this is te front:

```
await axios.post(`${HOST}/documentos`, data)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    update(ref(getDatabase(), `BD_PASTEUR/${record.ID}`), {
                        DOCUMENTOS: "DOCUMENTOS GENERADOS",
                    }).then(() => {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Documentos generados',
                            text: 'Los documentos se han generado correctamente',
                            icon: 'success'
                        });
                    });
                };
            }).catch((error) => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Oops',
                    text: 'Ha ocurrido un error, contacta al administrador',
                    icon: 'error'
                })
            });
```

Comment: Hasta el momento estoy usando Heroku

Comment: Heroku is a deployment platform, not your Java server code (Please use English on Stackoverflow)

Comment: StackOverflow is an English-*only* site; if you want to communicate in Spanish you can go to [es.so].

Comment: Could you host the files in drive or firebase storage and from there request them to edit and download them?

Comment: Sure. But that doesn't seem relevant to the question being asked. You need to return a `byte[]` from the HTTP server with a `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` HTTP response header. Your JS code can then download the file as a byte-stream... For expressJS see - https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download or https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile